vega lite colour text using a field
I have a stacked bar chart with text marks that I want coloured according to field 'text_value'.
This is what I have now, however the top text values should be coloured black according to the color condition in the text mark encoding.

{
"data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "xval": 1, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 5, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 8, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 1, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 9, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "title": null,
      "field": "yval",
      "sort": "descending"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "tooltip": true
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {"field": "category"},
        "order": {"field": "category"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "tooltip": true,
        "fontSize": 100
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "stack": "zero",
          "bandPosition": 0.5
        },
        "text": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.text_val == 1",
            "value": "black"
          },
          "value": "white"
        },
        "order": {"field": "category"}
      }
    }
  ]
}

Please note: It seems the 'text_value' field needs to be used somewhere else, but I don't need it anywhere except the condition.  Also the aggregation must be sum, as this is a simplified example.

UPDATE START

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": 200,
  "width": 800,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "xval": 1, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 5, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 8, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 1, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 9, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"stack": "xval", "as": ["v1", "v2"], "groupby": ["yval"]},
   {"calculate": "((datum.v2 - datum.v1)/2) + datum.v1", "as": "mid"},],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"title": null, "field": "yval", "sort": "descending"},
    "x2": {"field": "v2", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"title": null, "field": "v1", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "category"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "tooltip": true, "fontSize": 100},
      "encoding": {
          "x": {"title": null, "field": "mid", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"title": null, "field": "xval", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.text_val == 1", "value": "black"},
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

UPDATE END
Your hidden aggregate transform here:

is resulting in this:

i.e. the column you are referring to is lost.
You can either create a proper transform to do your own aggregate or instead just use a value that is available like yval

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "xval": 1, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 5, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 8, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 1, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 9, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {"y": {"title": null, "field": "yval", "sort": "descending"}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {"field": "category"},
        "order": {"field": "category"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "tooltip": true, "fontSize": 100},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "stack": "zero",
          "bandPosition": 0.5
        },
        "text": {
          "title": null,
          "field": "xval",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "aggregate": "sum"
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.yval == 'top'", "value": "black"},
          "value": "white"
        },
        "order": {"field": "category"}
      }
    }
  ]
}


Could you please give me more detail about "create a proper transform".  I've tried creating a transform after the data spec, but it give me undefined in the hidden data:   "transforms": [     {       "calculate": "datum.text_val = 1 ? 'white': 'black'",       "as": "text_colour"     }   ],

I'll update now.

I wanted to keep the aggregation, however I noticed for the dataset it doesn't make sense, so I've accepted your answer because it helped me most of the way.  I'll post the aggregation version below for others.

This is based on the above answer and adds aggregation, for which an extra data row
{"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},

is added.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": 200,
  "width": 800,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": "a", "xval": 1, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 5, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 8, "yval": "top", "text_val": 1},
      {"category": "a", "xval": 3, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "b", "xval": 1, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2},
      {"category": "c", "xval": 9, "yval": "bottom", "text_val": 2}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{        
        "op": "sum",
        "field": "xval",
        "as": "xvals"
    }],
      "groupby": ["yval", "category", "text_val"]
    },
    {"stack": "xvals", "as": ["v1", "v2"], "groupby": ["yval"]},
   {"calculate": "((datum.v2 - datum.v1)/2) + datum.v1", "as": "mid"}],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"title": null, "field": "yval", "sort": "descending"},
    "x2": {"field": "v2", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"title": null, "field": "v1", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "category"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "tooltip": true, "fontSize": 100},
      "encoding": {
          "x": {"title": null, "field": "mid", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"title": null, "field": "xvals", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum.text_val == 1", "value": "black"},
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

